# Accessing data from arrays very quickly

Tags: c++, performance, multidimensional-array

My problem is here.
I have four 3-dimensional tables which are a sort of look up tables ( 32x32x32 ) where I have to retrieve values in real time and very quickly in c++.
My main goal is computational time as a very large amount of operations have to be made, and good programming practice is secondary for this, as I’m less worried about code maintaining.
What is the best solution on the majority of personal computer to achieve this?
I’ve thought of storing the data on global variables and put them in a separate file and using them through declarations like “extern const float first[32][32][32];” or loading a vector from a file.
But the latter, I suppose, would be slower because data have to accessed through one more pointer.
Any other solution?

I made a search on the web, but this confused me more as I read different truths.
For example this two websites don’t seem to suggest the same thing (if I understand correctly): [site1](http://www.diku.dk/forskning/performance-engineering/Jesper/heaplab/heapsurvey_html/node17.html) , [site2](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/891039-array-performance-fix-size-vs-dynamic)

Comment: Optimization should be performed when you know there is a bottle neck. Here accessing the array is not.

Also it depends on what you consider as "real time". It means different things and as far as I can see, accessing an array that contains 32768 elements is real time on low end hardware too.

Comment: First, try obvious way: three-dimemsional array in the memory. Check, whether this is sufficient for you. Only if results are not good enough, think about optimization.

Comment: @Alex Farber, my goal is not to get a result who crosses a threshold. I would like to obtain the best performance I can get, and I wonder what is the right solution for this.

Comment: @Ram, the tables have to be used many many times to process each single image coming from a camera.

Comment: If you use some type of loops traversing the values in the array, you must think carefully of a proper nesting of loops, cache misses could be performance bottleneck in real-time.

Comment: @Michael, It is not completely clear what do you mean "traversing the values in the array". Anyway I don't think so, as I just have to retrieve a cell at a time, but a huge number of time. I'm quite sure I'm not far away the performance I need to get the application work, as I did something similar before. Just wanting to avoid slowing down and save some resources for other operations if possible.

Comment: Just to add that the values are not retrieved in cycles, but based on values I get in different points of the image.  
Everytime I have a different triplet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing data in a multidimensional array

```
float data[32][32][32];
data[i][j][k];
```

is exactly equivalent to accessing a flattened array

```
float data[32768];
data[i * 1024 + j * 32 + k];
```

There is no extra pointer involved, just arithmetic on the array indexes.

In terms of performance, an `extern const float [32][32][32]` will offer the compiler opportunities for whole program optimisation as it will have full access to the data and how you are using it.

Loading data from a file into a dynamic-sized `vector<vector<vector<float>>>` would result in multiple pointer indirections to access data elements; given that you know the size of the data, loading it into a `static float[32][32][32]` would be more efficient.

For data where the extents are unknown at compile time, a good option would be to use [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html):

```
typedef boost::multi_array<float, 3> array_type;
array_type A(boost::extents[32][32][32]);

A[i][j][k] = 5.0f;
```

Comment: I did not think that the two methods are equivalent.  
Maybe this is an answer to Ram's post?  
My confrontation was between a global array  
  "extern const float data[32][32][32] = {...};" 
and a vector loaded at runtime (I don't think it matters if global or local)
  "vector<vector<vector<float>>> data;"  
and whatever else could be useful.

Comment: Ah, didn't realise you were considering a `vector<vector<vector<float>>>`.  Yes, that'll be less performant; will update my answer.

Comment: @GiuseppeDini that second link is comparing fixed array access to heap array access; both involve a single pointer indirection.  Nested vector access involves multiple indirections so is slower.

Comment: Is there a way of using vector than offers the same performance of the array solution?
Maybe after this comment I should retag the question, but, as it is an opencv project, I also thought about loading the data in a Mat object from a file, which under the cover I guess is equivalent to 

`float *data = new float[32768];`

Comment: Not really; `vector` has issues with containing array types so you can't write `vector<float[32][32]>`.  If `Mat` is designed to be used as a multidimensional array then that's probably the best option.

Comment: @GiuseppeDini you might be interested in Boost.MultiArray: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Comment: @eecatmur very interesting. BTW I think that opencv’s Mat can really do the job in this case. Elements are accessed like this ‘Matdata.at<float>(i,j)’  or with a ‘i * 1024 + j * 32 + k’ logic, which seems to suggest that Mat contains an array-like object under the hood. Only I don’t know if ‘const’ would be an advantage.
[I've slightly cahanged your name because I don't know why it disappears if I write it correctly]

Comment: I don’t know where I misunderstood things but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176298/c-best-practices-of-dynamic-vs-static-memory-in-terms-of-cleanliness-and-spe) they seem to state that ‘float x[6];’ has an advantage over ‘float *x;’ in terms of speed. 
Maybe this will clarify why I say that I’m reading too many information that seem in contrast between them.

Comment: @GiuseppeDini that's referring to the speed of allocation; `float x[6]` just requires adjusting the stack pointer while `new float[6]` involves the heap allocator.  btw, my name disappears because anything you write on one of my answers is assumed to be addressed to me anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are performing an operation on each element, there is a fair chance that this can be performed in parallel. Since you are interested specifically in optimizing access time, you can consider treating the array as a 1D array for faster access.

```
   struct Object32P3 {
     union { 
    struct {float arr3[32][32][32]}; 
    struct {float arr1[32768]}; 
    }; 
    };
```

Accessing 1D array by offset is faster than a 3d array in tight loops.

the reason I say that accessing should not be the first place you have to try and optimize is because, you are performing some operation after accessing the elements and that is the best place to look and optimize.